# Yoneda lemma, bijection between sets of natural transformations

Tags: category-theory, functors

Let $Y: \cal A\to Set^{\cal A^{op}}$ be the Yonneda embedding and
$S:Set^{\cal A^{op}}\to Set$ an arbitrary functor.
How do I use the Yonneda lemma to obtain a bijection between natural transformations $hom(A,-)\to SY$ AND these: $hom(hom(-,A),-)\to S$.
See the second displayed formula [Here](https://books.google.cz/books?id=iXh6rOd7of0C&pg=PA82&dq=kan+extensions+can+always+be+chosen+as+a+hom-functor&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=kan%20extensions%20can%20always%20be%20chosen%20as%20a%20hom-functor&f=false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Yoneda lemma once to obtain  $\text{Nat}(\hom(\hom(-,A),-),-),S) \cong S(\hom(-,A))$. Use it a second time to obtain $\text{Nat}(\hom(A,-),SY) \cong SY(A)$ and then notice that $SY(A)=S(\hom(-,A))$.